# How to make device faster when opening code editors?

Tags: 20.04, toshiba-satellite

My device becomes heavy when I open a code editor and Google Chome, what is the problem?
[image: Device info - neofetch]

My device info here:

Comment: You haven't really given us a description of the problem.  You have a dual core CPU that is 12+ years old and only 4GB of RAM. What is the reason you believe that it should perform better? What is the actual problem that you're facing?

Comment: When I open visual studio code and google chrome the device become slow.

Comment: @SbbahEltag Well... yeah. It is going to be slow on an old computer. With 4GB RAM, I'm not surprised. If you're using an HDD, upgrading to an SSD may speed it up. But... old computers tend to be slow.

Comment: Both of those applications are demanding of resources, especially RAM, of which you don't have a lot.  You are also running GNOME which is a "heavy" desktop environment. Unfortunately it's probably likely that your problems have to do with lack of resources.

Comment: You're behind on *upgrades* & security fixes; a fully-updated 20.04 system won't be using an EOL & *unsupported* kernel like 5.11; the GA kernel of 5.4 is still supported and HWE should have been using 5.13 for a ~few weeks now.   Some editors are *light*, others are very *heavy* (esp. if IDE) but you gave no details; except a web browser (*that is a heavy & fully-featured one*)

Comment: This question essentially seems to boil down to "*When I open large, resource-hungry applications, they consume most of my system's resources*" which seems like the expected behavior. Your options are to add resources to your system or to use less resource-hungry applications.